# Joining fields values

Tags: python

I have classes structure like this:

```
class A(object):
    array = [1]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    array = [2, 3]

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

class C(B):
    array = [4]

    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print array
```

And when I do:

```
c = C()
```

I want it to join all their fields in the order of inheritance. And print [1, 2, 3, 4]. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the classes modify their *class attributes* at class-definition time (without boilerplate code inside each class definition), you'll need a class decorator or a metaclass.

If you use a class decorator, then you'll have to decorate each class individually.

If you use a metaclass, `class A`'s metaclass will be inherited by `class B` and `class C`, so you will only have to modify `class A`:

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        super(MetaA, cls).__init__(name, bases, clsdict)
        for base in bases:
            if hasattr(base, 'array'):
                cls.array = base.array + cls.array
                break

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaA
    array = [1]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    array = [2, 3]

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

class C(B):
    array = [4]

    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
```

yields

```
print(A.array)
# [1]

print(B.array)
# [1, 2, 3]

print(C.array)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

Well when you define `array` in each class, it's going to override the value of the inherited class.

If you want to do this, then change your class definitions, and add the `array` initialisation into the `__init__(self)` function of each class.

I.e.

```
class A(object):
    array = [1]
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.array += [2,3]

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        self.array += [4]
        print self.array
```

Comment: Is there way or not to write something in A class contructor that will join `array` for all of its children?

Comment: This is not a good solution, because it will modify the base classes' values of `array`, not just create joined versions for the subclasses.  After you instantiate `C`, then `A.array` will also equal `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  Also, if you instantiate `C` twice, `A.array` will become `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`, and so on.